# Create custom field with different names

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to create custom fields that have different name attributes so that I can access them by doing `req.body.name1` and `req.body.name2` My JS code is

```
$(document).on("click",".add",function(){
 var n= $(this).prev(".form-group" ).length+1;
 var temp = $(this).prev(".form-group" ).clone();
 $('input:first',temp).attr('placeholder','Custom Field').val("");
 $(this).prev( ".form-group" ).after(temp);
});
```

And my HTML is

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="customField" class="control-label">Custom Field</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customField" name="customField" placeholder="Your Field">
 </div>
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary add" id="add" value="Add Field"/>
```

I know I am missing the name attribute in my JS but Google was being unhelpful today. How can I change this to make it so that when the user clicks "Add Field" they will get another custom field added but with a different name that I can access from my server-side code. I also would like to limit the custom fields to 5. Not sure how I would do that without knowing how to change the name attribute.

Let me know if you require more code or anything else. I think I provided all the code needed.

Edit-- Something I realized after posting this is that the way I have it now doesn't work and that it would also add the `label` too which I would like to avoid adding every time.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need different names for each field? On the server you'll get an array in `req.body.name` if there are 2 or more fields called `name` in the request.

Comment: Oh.. Didn't know that, never had this issue before. Okay so I guess the only thing left is how to I duplicate the input/`form-group` and keep the spacing without the label in there to mess it up.